# Changing the extent of a shapefile in ArcMap for distribution modelling in R

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, shapefile, r, extents

I am currently trying to create a species distribution model in R using maxent. The shapefile I have is a map of an island. When viewed in ArcMap it has a set extent--in Lat and Long. I can successfully pull this into R and plot presence points. However, I cannot plot any points that are outside of the lat/long extent of the map's shapefile.

Is there a way of widening/expanding the extent of this shapefile so that I can plot points further offshore?

Comment: The 2-D envelope of a [shapefile](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) is located in the header (bytes 35-67, as little-endian doubles).  If R is using the header (vice scanning the actual geometry MBRs), you could change it easily enough in the language of your choice.

Comment: Cheers @Vince for posting so quickly! 
That sounds relatively straight forward. However, I am relatively novice and with my layman knowledge I don't really understand how I would go about doing what you have suggested.
Would you be able to walk me through it a bit more if possible? Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to change the extent of the actual data or just the plot? If it is just the plot you can use ylim and xlim to define the extent of the plot.

Create some example data

```
library(sp)
x <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(SpatialPoints(cbind(runif(10, -115, -110), runif(10, 30, 45))), 
                             data.frame(ID=1:10) )
y <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(SpatialPoints(cbind(runif(10, -115, -110), runif(10, 0, 15))), 
                             data.frame(ID=1:10) )
```

Here we use xlim and ylim to set the extent of the plot to the maximum of the two extents. The maximum extent can be found using bbox.

```
bbox( rbind(coordinates(x), coordinates(y)) ) 
plot(x, xlim = c(-114.3341119, -110.36854) , 
     ylim = c(0.3388812, 44.74403), pch = 20 )
  plot(y, pch=20, col="red", add=TRUE)
```

If you want to change the actual extent of an sp class object you can modify the bbox slot. This extent change would carry along when the data was read back to disk as a shapefile (eg., using writeOGR in rgdal).

```
x@bbox <- bbox( rbind(coordinates(x), coordinates(y)) )
  plot(x, pch = 20 )
  plot(y, pch=20, col="red", add=TRUE)
```

Please keep in mind that it is important to understand the data structures that you are working with. When you read a shapefile into R, unlike ArcGIS that points to the data and displays it, R is creating a new dataset of class sp and it is no longer a shapefile.

Comment: Thanks for you help!!
I think you have solved my question but just to double check..
My issue was that when I pulled in the shapefile from ArcGIS into R everything seemed fine and a map appeared as I had wanted and I could plot points okay. However, I could only plot points that had a lat/long location that fell in the extent defined in ArcGIS. Anything outside these coordinates would not show up in R. What in the above response would I need to do pre/post importing the shapefile into R to allow me to plot points further away from my original map?
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I addressed. If you plot x you will see that the plot extent does not encompass y, By changing the limits of the plot you change the plot extent to encompass the additional data without changing the source data, only the display. However, in my last example, where you modify the @bbox slot, you are changing the extent of x which will modify the data. By doing this you do not need to change the plot limits. This would be a critical step if you doing something like creating random samples that needed to match the larger extent.

Comment: Cheers man! That's work a treat!